# Galois group acts transitively

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

The question I am dealing with is: Let F be a field, $f(x)\in F[x]$ be irreducible and let $N/F$ be normal field extension. Let

$$f(x) = g_1(x) \cdot \dots \cdot g_r (x)$$

be the factorization of $f(x)$ into irreducibles in $N[x]$. Show that $G_{N/F}$ acts transitively on the $g_i$'s.

It doesn't really spezify what kind of field F is. So I don't know if I can assume $N/F$ is Galois. Or if I can assume that $f$ is separable. Because if I cant assume those things than I don't know how to do it. Please help! Thanks

Comment: I think $G_{N/F}$ acts on the $g_i$'s by acting on their coefficients. That action is like a permutation in the index set $\{1,2,\dots, r\}$. The question is, why is this action transitive?

Comment: Is it easier if we can assume that f is separable?

Comment: Consider the splitting field of $f$: $L/N$. Then $G_{L/F}$ acts transitively on the roots of $f$. If you want to find some $\sigma\in G_{N/F}$ that takes $g_i$ to $g_j$, consider some $\overline{\sigma}\in G_{L/F}$ that takes a root of $g_i$ to a root of $g_j$. The restriction of this element is your candidate.