# Show existence of $\sigma$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $K$ be a normal extension of $F$ and $f\in F[x]$ be irreducible over $F$.

Let $g_1, g_2$ be irreducible factors of $f$ in the ring $K[x]$.

How could we show that there exists $\sigma \in G(K/F)$ such that $g_2=\sigma (g_1)$ ?

Could  you give me a hint for that?

Comment: IMHO the same question has appeared [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/286826/11619). No answers, though. I'll keep looking...

Comment: A more promising [match](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2002864/11619). Further checking required to decide whether this is a dupe. May be [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/86778/11619)?

Answer (score 2):

Let $L/K$ be the splitting field of $f$. Let $\alpha_1$ be a root of $g_1$ and $\alpha_2$ be a root of $g_2$. From field theory, since $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ have the same minimal polynomial over $F$ and $L/F$ is normal, we get $\sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(L/F)$ such that $\sigma(\alpha_1) = \alpha_2$. Since $K/F$ is normal, $\sigma|_K \in \operatorname{Aut}(K/F)$, still with $\sigma|_K(\alpha_1) = \alpha_2$.

Now $g_2$ is irreducible in $K$ and $g_2(\alpha_2) = 0 \in L$, so $g_2$ is the minimal poolynomial of $\alpha_2$ over $K$. However, $\sigma|_K(g_1)$ is also irreducible in $K$, and $(\sigma|_K(g_1))(\alpha_2) = (\sigma|_K(g_1))(\sigma(\alpha_1)) = \sigma|_K(g_1(\alpha_1)) = 0$, so $\sigma|_K(g_1)$ is also the minimal polynomial of $\alpha_2$ over $K$.

Since minimal polynomial is unique, we conclude $\sigma|_K(g_1) = g_2$.

---

A counter-example when $K/F$ is not normal is $F=\Bbb Q$ and $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$ and $f = X^3-2 \in F[X]$, with $f = (X-\sqrt[3]2)(X^2+\sqrt[3]2X+\sqrt[3]4) \in K[X]$.

Comment: Sorry but could you explain why this counter-example works? Namely why there is no such automorphism?

Comment: Am I right it is because your irreducible factors of $f$, namely $X-\sqrt[3]2$ and $X^2+\sqrt[3]2X+\sqrt[3]4$ have different degrees?

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the reason.